# DataTables count rows by text in cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a simple DataTable for which I'm adding a class called `selected` when the user clicks the row:

```
$("#datatable-buttons tbody").delegate("tr", "click", function (event) {
     var $row = $(event.target);
     if ($row[0].tagName !== "TR") $row = $row.parent();
     $row.toggleClass("selected");
     if (event.ctrlKey === false) {
        $row.toggleClass("selected");
        $row.siblings().removeClass("selected");
     }
});
```

Inside the same function I'm trying to count the rows that have the second column different from `---`

```
var clickedD = 0;
table.rows('.selected').every(function () {
      if (this.cell('.selected', 1).data() != "---")
          clickedD++;
 });
```

But when there are more than one row selected it counts just the first row with this class. Is there a way to get the number of rows that are selected (have the class `selected`) with the second cell of each row different from `---`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the `row().data()` array. And use the API more heavily. Here is a more simplified version :

```js
table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
  table.row(this).nodes().to$().toggleClass('selected');
  var count = 0;
  table.rows('.selected').every(function() {
    if (table.row(this).data()[1] !== '---') count ++;
  })
  $('#count').text(count+' selected rows with #2 col different from ---')
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/q6d8wqLk/**

If you have a JSON based dataSource,, you can use

```
if (table.row(this).data().secondColData !== '---') count ++;
```

---

**FYI**: [delegate() is now deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.0/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Works perfectly! :)